# Creating a Database Diagram in SSMS - Auth Failed

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I am trying to generate a database diagram from an existing SQLExpress database that I own but I am getting this error:

```
Database diagram support objects cannot be installed because this database does not have a valid owner.  To continue, first use the Files page of the Database Properties dialog box or the ALTER AUTHORIZATION statement to set the database owner to a valid login, then add the database diagram support objects.
```

I am the owner according to the properties:
[image]

I did try this but was not in the correct syntax

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::GuitaristDB TO PDC1\tcastonzo;
```

This executed but probably not correct

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::GuitaristDB TO tcastonzo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the user `PDC1\tcastonzo` (which is a domain or computer account) has a login to the SQL Server.

The user `tcastonzo` looks to be a SQL account, which is separate from the `PDC1\tcastonzo` account.

What credentials do you currently use to connect to the SQL Server?

Comment: I use windows authentication

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the **owner** of the database to either **SA or NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM**.

1. Right click the database you want to change AUTHORIZATION and click
   **Properties**. A window/dialog will open.
2. At the left side of the dialog click **Files**
3. From the Right side change the Owner as your own

Then logged-in with the changed user. It will solve your problem.

Try and enjoy

[image]